# How to join a path that connects two parts of a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, fill

I am working in Adobe Illustrator on creating a logo for housegan.com and I'm having trouble joining the path so that I can fill different color in the top and bottom portion of the circles (see image)

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Object Join - complains that I need to select two separate path
- Direct selection join (is this the same thing) - to join, you must select two end points of the same or two different paths.

I need to do this all the way down the circle but I figure the same technique can be applied multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have different fills you need to have separate objects.

1. Create your paths across the ellipse to define the shapes you want.
2. Select all the paths *and* the ellipse.
3. Go to Pathfinder (Window> Pathfinder) and choose Divide (far left of the lower row).
4. Go to Object> Ungroup.
5. Select each individual shape and add Fill color of your choice.

[image]

Comment: wow. I find this insane. thank you very much